# Android notificatoin light for battery charging indicator

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I want to show notification light when battery is charging (Plugged In) via app. Getting battery status is not an issue but turning on light is really hard for me. I want my phone to show red light if battery is under 15% then orange till 89% then green light when battery charge reach 90%-100%.

So far i use Broadcast receiver to get charging status when user plugin or disconnect battery charging.

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class Battery_Indicator_Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG="###Battery Status###";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Battery Intent "+intent);
        int status=intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,-1);
        boolean isCharging=status==BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                status==BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
        Log.d(TAG,"Battery Status FUll or Charging "+ BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING+" "+BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL+" "+isCharging);
        if (isCharging){
            // Here i need to turn notification light on 

        }
    }


}
```

Manifest file

```
   <receiver android:name=".Battery_Indicator_Broadcast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"></action>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: You do not have direct control over that LED, except perhaps on rooted devices. Some devices do not even have one. Many devices do not have one with varying colors.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am using nexus 5 rooted but as you said it won't work on other devices without root. Is there any way i can achieve my task for most of the device

Comment: Not really. The only way a regular app can affect the LED is via a `Notification`. There is no requirement for any device to actually *use* the LED for notifications, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you help me for my rooted nexus 5 device